# Как создать Триггер sql на удаление данных из таблиц?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть таблицы:

```
dbo_student(kod_stud(primary key),Name_ini,SName,Name,FName,N_in_group,Kod_group
dbo_groups(Kod_group(primary key),Kod_men,Kod_zhurn,K_navch_plan,kilk)
```

Необходимо написать триггер: При удаление студента надо проверить есть ли еще в группе студенты и потом если нет удалить группу. Я реализовал только нахождение группы,если в ней нет студентов:

```
delete from  dbo_groups
where  dbo_groups.Kod_group= (
select q.Kod_group
from dbo_groups q
where not exists (
select g.Kod_stud,q.Kod_group
from dbo_student g
where q.Kod_group = g.Kod_group))
```

Comment: Вас интересует именно конструкция создания триггера?

Comment: Не могу понять как дописать его...если я например удаляю 
delete dbo_student
where kod_stud = 1 и это был последний студент в группе,таблицы dbo_groups,то она должна удалиться...Вот это я и не могу уловить...мало опыта в разработке триггеров,но нужно сдавать лабу..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
CREATE TRIGCGER OnStudentDeleted
ON dbo_students
AFTER DELETE AS
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM
        dbo_groups
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                dbo_students S
            WHERE
                S.N_in_group = dbo_groups.kod_group
        )
END
```

Этот триггер будет срабатывать после удаления строк из таблицы `dbo_students` и удалять **ВСЕ** группы без студентов. На сколько это будет быстро раьботать - не знаю, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это не очень хорошее решение. Можно проверять только группы в которых состояли удаленные студенты (они будут в таблице `deleted`).

Я бы наверное сделал хранимку, которая на вход получала бы `ID` студента, удаляла его (запомнив перед этим его группу) а потом смотрла есть ли у этой группы еще студенты и, если их нет, удаляла бы ее.